# Share jsp Session between 2 J2EE applications Deployed in Tomcat Server

Tags: hibernate, jsp, session, tomcat, jakarta-ee

hello i'm working on web application using hibernate and when i try this application in the project generated by eclipse web service i got an error and i can't resolve it

this is it:

[hibernate class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525431/hibernate-class-not-found-exception)

so i have to work in two project,

so how can i share a session atribute between two dynamic web project ?

for example in my first project i login like that:

```
        String Username=request.getParameter("UserName");
    String Password=request.getParameter("passWord");

    if(Username!=null && Password!=null ){

     Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.currentSession(); 
     Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction(); 
     tx.commit(); 

   Query qEtudiant = hibernateSession.createQuery("from Etudinat where UserName =    :userSID and Password=:psw");
 qEtudiant.setParameter("userSID", Username);
 qEtudiant.setParameter("psw", Password);
 Etudinat e =(Etudinat) qEtudiant.uniqueResult();

 Query qEnseignant = hibernateSession.createQuery("from Enseignant where UserName = :userSID and Password=:psw");
 qEnseignant.setParameter("userSID", Username);
 qEnseignant.setParameter("psw", Password);
 Enseignant en =(Enseignant) qEnseignant.uniqueResult();

 Query qadmin = hibernateSession.createQuery("from Administrateur where UserName = :userSID and Password=:psw");
 qadmin.setParameter("userSID", Username);
 qadmin.setParameter("psw", Password);
 Administrateur admin =(Administrateur) qadmin.uniqueResult();



 if(e!=null){

    session.setAttribute("UserName",Username);
    session.setAttribute("Nom", e.getNom());
    session.setAttribute("Prenom", e.getPrenom());
    session.setAttribute("type", "Etudiant");
    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

         }
     else 
         if(en!=null){

                             session.setAttribute("UserName",Username);
                        session.setAttribute("Nom",    en.getNom());
                        session.setAttribute("Prenom", en.getPrenom());
                        session.setAttribute("type", "Enseignant");
                        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
                         RequestDispatcher rd   =request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                         rd.forward(request, response); 
                    }
         else
                if(admin!=null){

                                    session.setAttribute("UserName",Username);
                                  session.setAttribute("Nom", admin.getNom());
                                 session.setAttribute("Prenom",   admin.getPrenom());
                                session.setAttribute("type",   "Administrateur");
                                HibernateUtil.closeSession();
                                 RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                                 rd.forward(request, response);
                                }
                else{   HibernateUtil.closeSession();
                        RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp?err=true");
                        rd.forward(request, response);

                    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sticking your hibernate code into a third project, and it expose it to the first two via JNDI lookup. This articlue describes how to bind a SessionFactory into Tomcat's JNDI namespace:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJNDI-boundSessionFactorywithTomcat41

Comment: i want to share a jsp session not hibernate session thx for the answer